# Different Users role , each in one table

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

in my database i have admins , merchants and drivers . 
All of them share many attributes like name/email/phone/credentials..etc
So , the way i designed my database is a tabled called "users" and table for each role [admin,merchant,driver] where shared attributes are stored in users table. 
My questions is do i have to maintain an ID for each role for example [ driver_id , merchant_id ] and link it to the user_id or depending only on the user_id and storing the type of the user in users table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of queries you'll run on your database, you could have a few different options. If you're going to query the user table without needing information from the role-specific tables, then just store the type of user i.e. **role** in the `users` table.

However, if you are going to be including role-specific information that is in the admin, merchant, or driver tables, then it may be beneficial to include a unique `merchant_id`, `admin_id` or `driver_id` in the user table to designate a role and simultaneously act as ID into the appropriately associated table.

Diagramming this in database modeling software can help to identify the relationships between different data pieces within your application to better design your tables and attributes.

Comment: It depends on your application needs and access patterns. I've updated my response to reflect your question.